# How do I convert a long to a LocalDateTime with jOOQ

Tags: java, jooq

I have a database where a date is represented as a long (BIGINT). I want to fetch the data into a record `CheckIn`, like the following

```
context.select(CHECKINS.CHECKIN_TIME,
                CHECKINS.CHECKOUT_TIME
        ).from(CHECKINS)
        .fetch(Records.mapping(CheckIn::new));
```

The two columns in CHECKINS are represented as `TableField<CheckinsRecord, Long>`. `CheckIn` is defined as

```
public record CheckIn(LocalDateTime checkIn, LocalDateTime checkOut) {
}
```

Can I convert `CHECKINS.CHECKIN_TIME` to a LocalDateTime right in the select, or do I need to do the conversion later?

Answer (score 2):

you can use the `java.time.ZoneId` class to specify a time zone for the `LocalDateTime` object, like this:

```
context.select(CHECKINS.CHECKIN_TIME,
                CHECKINS.CHECKOUT_TIME
        ).from(CHECKINS)
        .fetch(r -> new CheckIn(
                Instant.ofEpochMilli(r.get(CHECKINS.CHECKIN_TIME)).atZone(ZoneId.of("UTC")).toLocalDateTime(),
                Instant.ofEpochMilli(r.get(CHECKINS.CHECKOUT_TIME)).atZone(ZoneId.of("UTC")).toLocalDateTime()
        ));
```